# Having trouble storing different numbers entered by user in a loop as different values

Tags: javascript

I'm taking a class on computer programming, and I have an assignment where I have to make a loop in which users enter data into a prompt, and at the end I will output the lowest, highest, average, and total of that data. The problem is, I can't figure out how to have that data stored as different values every time. Btw I'm using javascript, and the project has to be done with that language.

````
var g = 1;
var points = alert("Please enter the scores of the player in the prompts.");
var totalPoints = 0;
do {
  var pointsCount = Number(prompt("Please enter how many points the user entered in Game " + g + ":"))
  i++
  g++
  totalPoints += pointsCount
  
} while (pointsCount != -1)
alert("*** Your Player Stats *** /n" + " Minimum points: " + Math.min(pointsCount) + " Maximum points: " + Math.max(pointsCount) + " Average points: " + totalPoints/i + " Total points: " + totalPoints);*```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store data outside the loop and update it when needed. You don't have `i` varaible in your code. You can use here a while loop with true condition so it repeats infinitely, and break out of it using some condition (e.g. `-1` as input). Take a look at the code below.

```js
let totalPoints = 0;
let minPoints;
let maxPoints;
let numberOfGames = 0;

while(true){
  let points = Number(prompt("Please enter how many points for this game"))

  // skip invalid data
  if(isNaN(points)){
    continue;
  }

  // loop exit condition
  if(points === -1) break;

  // set min if not undefined or lower than recorded
  if(!minPoints || points < minPoints){
    minPoints = points;
  }

  // same as above but for max
  if(!maxPoints || points > maxPoints){
    maxPoints = points;
  }

  totalPoints += points;
  numberOfGames++;
}

alert("*** Your Player Stats ***" + "\nMinimum points: " + minPoints + "\nMaximum points: " + maxPoints + "\nAverage points: " + totalPoints/numberOfGames + "\nTotal points: " + totalPoints);
```